# how to write a function which produces data to different bindings based on custom logic

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

A regular Spring Cloud Stream function looks like this (taken from [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_overview)):

```
@Bean
public Function<String, String> toUpperCase() {
    return s -> s.toUpperCase();
}
```

Considering not using [a reactive approach](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functions_with_multiple_input_and_output_arguments), I wonder whether it's possible to make different transformations based on custom logic and/or send the result to a different "out" binding? Something like this:

```
@Bean
public Function<String, String> transform() {
    return s -> {
      if (s.equals("A")) {
        return s.toUpperCase();       //this wants to be sent to toUpperCase-out-0
      } else if (s.equals("B")) {
        return s.toLowerCase();       //this wants to be sent to toLowerCase-out-0
      } else {
        return "unsupported";         //this wants to be sent to unsupported-out-0
      }
    };
}
```

Also, here we have the same return type (String) but maybe it could be required to return objects of different classes from each branch (by using `Object`/abstract class/etc. as a return type of the whole function).

I can imagine a solution with a `Consumer` instead of `Function` in which we make different `StreamBridge` calls, but maybe it's possible to do the same with a `Function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `Function`, use a `Consumer` instead and send the outputs using the `StreamBridge`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

Comment: You can also benefit form routing feature fo spring-cloud-stream/function - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing

Comment: Specifically: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_spring_cloud_stream_sendto_destination